# Java assertj double containsSequence

Tags: java, unit-testing, floating-point, precision, assertj

How do I specify the double/float tolerance to assertj while comparing a double sequence? Here, `items` is a `List<ScoredItem>` and `ScoredItem` has 2 attributes `itemId` and `score`.

```
assertThat(items).extracting("score").containsSequence(3.0, 2.0, 1.0, 0.35, 0.2);
```

This is throwing an exception during unit tests.

```
java.lang.AssertionError: 
Expecting:
 <[3.0, 2.0000000298023224, 1.0, 0.3500000052154064, 0.20000000298023224]>
to contain sequence:
 <[3.0, 2.0, 1.0, 0.35, 0.2]>
```

I also tried:

```
assertThat(items).extracting("score").containsSequence(new double[]{3.0, 2.0, 1.0, 0.35, 0.2}, Offset.offset(0.01));
```

...but no luck :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since this is extracted from a list, you have to call the generic method using `usingComparatorForType` before calling the `containsSequence` (Thanks to [Joel](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51757857/10172196) who corrected my reversed sequence).  Then you can pass in the `DoubleComparator`.

```
assertThat(items)
   .extracting("score")
   .usingComparatorForType(new DoubleComparator(0.2), Double.class)
   .containsSequence(3.0, 2.0, 1.0, 0.35, 0.2);
```

If `items` is just a `double []`, then you just need to call the method `usingComparatorWithPrecision`

```
assertThat(items)
    .usingComparatorWithPrecision(0.5)
    .containsSequence(3.0, 2.0, 1.0, 0.35, 0.2);
```

or replace the `offset` from the second line with `withPrecision`

```
assertThat(items).extracting("score")
    .containsSequence(new double[]{3.0, 2.0, 1.0, 0.35, 0.2}, withPrecision(0.5));
```

I've test this with AssertJ 3.9.1 using the following code:

```
public class ScoredItem {
    public int itemId;
    public double score;

    public ScoredItem(int i, double s) {
        itemId = i;
        score = s;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<ScoredItem> items = new ArrayList<ScoredItem>();
        items.add(new ScoredItem(1,3.0));
        items.add(new ScoredItem(1,2.0));
        items.add(new ScoredItem(1,1.1));
        items.add(new ScoredItem(1,0.33));
        items.add(new ScoredItem(1,0.22));

        assertThat(items)
            .extracting("score")
            .usingComparatorForType(new DoubleComparator(0.2), Double.class)
            .containsSequence(3.0, 2.0, 1.0, 0.35, 0.2);

    }
}
```

Comment: Neither of those work for me. For the first, I don't see `usingComparatorWithPrecision` (assertj version 3.9.1). The second solution again complains with `Expecting:
  <[3.0, 2.0000000298023224, 1.0, 0.3500000052154064, 0.20000000298023224]>
to contain sequence:
  <[[3.0, 2.0, 1.0, 0.35, 0.2], Offset[value=0.5]]>`

Answer (score 1):

@Magdop is correct (except for calling `usingComparatorWithPrecision` after the assertion).

Using 3.10.0, this test pass:

```
@Test
public void containsSequence_with_precision() {
  // GIVEN
  double[] scores = { 3.0, 2.0000000298023224, 1.0, 0.3500000052154064, 0.20000000298023224 };
  // THEN
  assertThat(scores).containsSequence(new double[] { 3.0, 2.0, 1.0, 0.35, 0.2 }, withPrecision(0.01));
  assertThat(scores).usingComparatorWithPrecision(0.01).containsSequence(new double[] { 3.0, 2.0, 1.0, 0.35, 0.2 });
  assertThat(scores).usingComparatorWithPrecision(0.01).containsSequence(3.0, 2.0, 1.0, 0.35, 0.2);
  assertThat(scores).usingComparatorWithPrecision(0.0001).containsSequence(3.0, 2.0, 1.0, 0.35, 0.2);
  // fails as expected when uncommented
  // assertThat(scores).usingComparatorWithPrecision(0.0000000001).containsSequence(3.0, 2.0, 1.0, 0.35, 0.2);
}
```

`usingComparatorWithPrecision` needs to be called before the assertion otherwise AssertJ won't use it.

`withPrecision` is an alias of `offset` (a bit more readable IMHO).